# Call a non static methode in a static SQLiteDatabase class

Tags: java, android, exception

i want to display a msg to the user (msg box or Toast) when exception happend in a static SQLite Database class that i use.

the problem is that i cant call a non static method in a static class , how can i handle this.

this is the class

```
private static SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(Context aContext) {
```

and i want to add something like this in the class when exception happen but `context` generates the problem of reference to non static in static class.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use the "getApplicationContext()" function, which is a nonstatic method.  You can't call nonstatic methods from static ones.  Why don't you just use the context that is passed in?  i.e.,

```
Context context = aContext;
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Thanks but i have problem to create it in a thread do u have any idea how can i Handle it